# Images not displayed when Assets Lib contain a collections of folders

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, macos, swiftui

I have a collection of folder and subfolders with images at the end of them. I tried displaying the image with something like

```
Image("folder/subFolder1/subFolder2/image.png")
```

All the images are added in Asset lib.

I do not see anything. Is this the wrong way to load and store images.
If yes, please let me know what would be the best way here.
The images are expected to be persistent and not change for a long time.

Comment: "what would be the best way"  The best way?  How do you decide which is the best?

Comment: So, I decided to use Assets lib to store images in PNG format and load them on run time. Is there a more optimized way?
That s what I meant by "Best way"

Comment: what is `Asset lib`, do you mean in the `Assets.xcassets` ?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the wrong terminology. Still learning @workingdog

Comment: if your images are in the `Assets.xcassets`, then just use `Image("image.png")`, works for me. The "system" will find the images.

Comment: Weirdly enough, not using the file extension is displaying the image. In this case, not using ".png"

Comment: most likely, you do not have `.png` file extension for the images in your Assets.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So let me show you some ways that makes you free to typing all that folders after each other!

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let urlOfImage = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "swiftPunk", withExtension: "png")
    
    var body: some View {

        // loading from Bundle:
        
        if let unwrappedURL: URL = urlOfImage {
            if let unwrappedUIImage: UIImage = UIImage(contentsOfFile: unwrappedURL.path) {
                Image(uiImage: unwrappedUIImage)
                    .resizable()
                    .scaledToFit()
                    .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
                    .cornerRadius(10.0)
            }
        }
        
        Text("Hello, world!").bold()

        // loading from Assets:
        
        Image("swiftPunk")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFit()
            .frame(width: 300, height: 300)
            .cornerRadius(10.0)

    }
}
```

*So you need to use just this code:*

```
Image("image")
```

[image]

[image]

### Results:

[image]

Comment: put all those folders in `Assets.xcassets` like the OP has, and all you
have to do is `Image("image")` and it will work.
You don't have to "...typing all that folders after each other!", or add a bunch of lines of code.

Comment: my comment is this, create all those folders in `Assets.xcassets` 
and all you have to do is `Image("swiftPunk")` and the image will show.
There is no need for anything else.

Comment: I see what you have done, sorry if I offended you. See also my comments, a few hours before your answer.